# Get Google+ count : Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus

I followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012357/facebook-twitter-linkedin-share-link-count) to get the google plus count, everything work fine if I follow 100%. 
But If I like to create my own API key from google developers console, then i keep getting the above error.

Things i have did but still failed

1. Create Server API Key from both new and old Developers console (not sure some say old console able to solve this issue)
2. Enable Almost all API under APIS.
3. Try to key in my public IP in "Allowed IP" or leave it blank.

Anything I did wrong?