# Different Approach to count Facebook, Twitter, Google+ Shares via jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, social-networking

I have read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012357/facebook-twitter-linkedin-share-link-count) and I also have searched on google to get the total number of social media share button's counts but I realize that this is not an easy task especially for Google+ and also if you have multiple buttons for multiple links on a Single Page.

So I'm trying achieve this by using a different approach via jQuery. [Link...](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

[image]

I want to get and calculate the total number of shares as text number inside the count box and I have read that jQuery .contents() can access `iframe` HTML elements, So I want to select the the `iframe` that generated by the share buttons and select the count's element id and get the total numbers of shares inside a `<div>????</div>` tag on my webpage. But still no Success...

Please help me to do this & Here is the sample JSFiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV7kC/6/)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! & BTW I'm a beginner & using ASP.NET WebMatrix.

**[Edited]**

**I really need a proper and useful solution to achieve this.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use the API's it would be a whole lot quicker rather than using jQuery's content.

eg http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.co.uk

returns the number of times that url has been shared etc

```
{"count":92127,"url":"http:\/\/www.google.co.uk\/"}
```

Facebook and Google have their own api's which you can also check the counts on.

Comment: What about getting the total and place it inside the `<div>????</div>` tag and have multiple buttons for multiple links on a Single Page? & I'm a beginner and I think it's too complex:)

Comment: Yes but @MaryMelody ... We are not here to do your job for you. We are here to help you solve small problems you encounter while working it out for yourself.

Comment: it should be noted (in case you find this) that the urls.api.twitter.com no longer works I found this searching for how do I find the google+ count in an API, saw the twitter one and tried it... dead. oh well