# An alternative to the now-deprecated Twitter endpoint count?

Tags: json, twitter, count, tweets

Relative newbie here :)

Since twitter just recently disabled their endpoint count (http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=), which they announced [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform), what would be a good alternative to get the current number of tweets per URL, with "good" being a JSON and hundreds of requests per day?

Only thing I found that might be good is [Topsy's search by link](http://topsy.com/links).

Comment: I guess [Twitter's REST APIs] (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) may be good, but I don't know how to use the service...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, you can try

http://opensharecount.com/

or look at this post. The first method works

[How do I Fetch Twitter Share Count via PHP after the upcoming update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746602/how-do-i-fetch-twitter-share-count-via-php-after-the-upcoming-update)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand what you meant by "The first Link". I'm also trying Gnip (I wonder why the ask you to contact them and not provide a registration link),

Comment: Opensharecount works only for one site once you registered (count tweet on your site) . I was talking about this method that works https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q="bbc.co.uk/programmes/b039ctgc"

Comment: Thanks @user3787735, but this page does not contain that actual number of tweets. And counting is not straightforward as you need to scroll to get more results.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, http://opensharecount.com uses Twitter's REST API on your behalf so you don't have to do the counting and storing of previous result counts (the search API only returns data that is up to a week old or so, so you have to keep track of what the most recent search result was the previous time you counted or the count will go off).

OpenShareCount returns JSON in exactly the same way the old Twitter API did, all you need to do is replace the broken URL with the new one.  You do need to sign up though, because it needs to do searches on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks - but it will not return the count for any URL (or any domain). In many cases it will return a zero, where, in fact, it's more than zero. In some of these cases, it takes opensharecount time, up to hours, to get the numbers. Plus - if they indeed use Twitter's REST API, it contains a limit of up to 100 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a different Twitter API, we are effectively counting thousands of tweets. And yes, the service is limited to the domain you sign up with but nothing stops you from signing up with multiple twitter accounts, one per domain you need info for.