# How to share the current page with the Facebook,LinkedIn and Twitter Share Button?

Tags: php, html, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but this case is different. I'm trying to make a Facebook button that is sharing the current URL but I have no idea how to do this.My question is : What should I put instead of 'homepage' so that these buttons share the page the user is currently on instead of a specific URL ?
Here's what the current code looks like (I replaced the website's URL by homepage) :

```
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='homepage' target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-facebook-4-icon-32.png" alt="Facebook">
</a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=homepage" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-linkedin-4-icon-32.png" alt="LinkedIn">
</a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=homepage" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-twitter-4-icon-32.png" alt="Twitter">
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook,Twitter,LinkedIn, share link count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012357/facebook-twitter-linkedin-share-link-count)

Comment: I understand what you're thinking but I'm trying to get these buttons to share the page I'm currently on rather than getting the counter.

Comment: Are you currently using a CMS or framework?

Comment: Try https://www.sharethis.com/

Comment: I'm using framework and thank you, I'll try sharethis.com

Comment: So what _is_ your actual question ...?

Comment: I've tried sharethis.com and the buttons aren't displayed on the website. My question is what should I put instead of homepage so that the page that the user is currently reading will be the page that will be shared on Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Get the current URL
<?php
$Url = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$Url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
?>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $Url; ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-facebook-4-icon-32.png" alt="Facebook">
</a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php echo $Url; ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-linkedin-4-icon-32.png" alt="LinkedIn">
</a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $Url; ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/25/1434621881-iconmonstr-twitter-4-icon-32.png" alt="Twitter">
</a>
```

Comment: @DumontIrou Thanks for the comment. Can you please mark it as complete?