# Share Count on Twitter, Linkedin, Pinterest and Instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, social-networking

I have tried

> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012357/facebook-twitter-linkedin-share-link-count`

But in this link Linkedin always give 0 count where i have just shared the link twice on linkedin.
AND
On Twitter api is not working to get share count.
AND
On Pinterest i don't know when i share the content or url on pinterest the only image get shared then how i can get the count of shared url on it.
I am doing this in rails as well as in js I have also tried many Gems Such as

```
 > scouter
   social_url_stats
   share_counts
   social_share_count
```

But in all this gem i didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to sell social media signals for 7 years already, so I could give you the answer you seek.

First of all you're referring to a question from 2014. Long story short - LinkedIn deprecated the endpoints used to retrieve the share counts for URLs, so did Twitter in August 2016. So forget those. When it comes to Pinterest - you could use this, in the following example you will see the amount of Pins the URL https://stackoverflow.com/ has: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=https://stackoverflow.com/